# Image viewer/editor with CamanJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to make a simple image viewer application using Electron and with the possibility to edit images. I am using CamanJS for image manipulation effects but I have a small problem. When I load the folder with all images, I can scroll through them, also, I can apply some filters to image number 3 for example, save it and scroll no next one. But when I am trying to edit another image, say number 5, when I press the button it renders the image nr 3 and apply the effects to image nr 3. I have tried to resolve this bug but with no success. Can someone help me? Bellow is some code.

Here is the image on the "web page"

```
<canvas id="currentImage" class="img-thumb center"></canvas>
```

I have an array of indexes with images from the folder and I iterate through it to change the image that is displayed. Below is the function how I change the image:

```
var onPreviousClick = function() {
  var currentImageId = $currentImage.data('currentIndex');
  if (currentImageId > 0) {
    showImage(--currentImageId);
  }
};
```

And this is how I apply the Lomo effect to the image:

```
$lomobtn.on('click', function() {
  Caman('#currentImage', function() {
    this.lomo().render();
  });
});
```

I suppose that is something related to `this`. First time when I press the button it references to the first image, and second time when I press the button it also references to the first image.

**UPDATE**

I find out that I have to use the function `reloadCanvasData()` to refresh the data from canvas, but I can't find out how to use this function. https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/src/core/caman.coffee#L387-L392
Can someone help me to use this function? Tried different methods to call this function and I receive and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a few months old question, but hopefully still relevant for you or someone else.

---

I had the same issue. Just use it like this:

```
$lomobtn.on('click', function() {
  Caman('#currentImage', function() {
    this.reloadCanvasData() // <--- here, before you apply your filter
    this.lomo().render();
  });
});
```

Comment: ye, I have figured out that. Anyway, I will accept as a correct answer.